# Sorting a UITableView by date and name with NSSortDescriptor, Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, unrecognized-selector

I have a UITableViewController that's currently being sorted by dates. I'm using `Core Data` with `NSFetchedResultsController` and I want to introduce a further sorting by names as well.

My model is :

Transaction Entity
Relationship to Dates Entity
Relationship to Person Entity

My `fetchedResultsController` code is like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    if ([self.timelineSearchBar.text length] > 0) {
        NSPredicate *predName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whoBy.name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.timelineSearchBar.text];
        NSPredicate *predOccasion = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"occasion.title CONTAINS[c] %@", self.timelineSearchBar.text];
        NSPredicate *predSubOccasion = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subevent.title CONTAINS[c] %@", self.timelineSearchBar.text];
        NSPredicate *compPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predName, predOccasion, predSubOccasion]];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:compPredicate];
    }
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dates.dateOfEvent" ascending:NO];


    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionDateFormatter" cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

So the `sortDescriptor` right now is sorting the the dates. The `sectionTitles` is a conversion from NSDate to NSString.

I tried the following code to add another `sortDescriptor`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"whoBy.name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, sortByName, nil]];
```

The app crashes with this error:

```
-[__NSArrayI key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702237c0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702237c0'
```

All I want to achieve is to make sure the entries that are sorted by the dates, are sorted by names as well.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting array of arrays of sort descriptors. Fix this line:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort, sortByName, nil]];
```

to:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sort, sortByName];
```

Comment: Thanks so much @thom_ek - that's really perfect - great catch and thanks for the help - sorry for the basic question!